# Transform Varags via Function

Tags: java, variadic-functions

Suppose I have two variadic functions in Java8:

```
public static Class3 func1(Class1... t){ ... }
public static Class3 func2(Class2... t){ ... }
```

and a function

```
public static Class2 transform(Class1 source){ ... }
```

which transforms objects of Class1 into objects of Class2. What is the most succint (and hopefully, efficient) way of calling func2 in func1 with every Class1-object transformed into objects of Class2 by means of the transform-function?

EDIT: The return types are not important. I'm looking for an idiom similar to:

```
public static Class3 func1(Class1... t){ 
    return func2( doTransformMagic(t) );
}
```

I'm aware that I can treat them as Arrays and write something like

```
public static Class3 func1(Class1... t){
    Class2[] target = new Class2[t.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; ++i){
        target[i] = transform(t[i]);
    }
    return func2(target);
}
```

I was asking if there are any build-in idioms for doing this more succintly.

Comment: Your `func1` and `func2` miss return types. What do you actually want to do? For each of `ti` in argument `t` of `func1` do `func2(transform(ti))`?

Comment: @lexicore I've re-written the question, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no nice short way to do this. In particular it is not possible to make use of the fact that `func2` is a varargs method. You're going to have to call `func2` by passing a new array.

With Java 8 you can do

```
public static void func1(Class1... t) {
    func2(Arrays.stream(t).map(SomeClass::transform).toArray(Class2[]::new));
}
```

With all versions from Java 5 you can do

```
public static void func1(Class1... t) {
    Class2[] arr = new Class2[t.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
        arr[i] = transform(t[i]);
    func2(arr);
}
```

Comment: Even in Java 8, I'd prefer the latter solution.  It's likely to perform better than the first solution, due to the overhead of creating a stream.  I also find it easier to read.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I agree. I generally prefer for loops to streams. In this case I like the explicitness of seeing that precisely one array is allocated.